# use of mvvm pattern in wpf application

Tags: wpf

i am new to wpf and i am designing a client-server application using wpf for UI
i have one view - view model, datalist and communication model
my view and view model will form one user control
following are my doubts:

1. if i keep my datalist inside viewmodel, how other view model can access it
2. if i keep my datalist in application so that any view can access it , whether my view model will be able to update it through binding
3. it will be good design if my view model calls my communication model directly or should i keep a wraper class in between.

thanx

sarika

Answer (score 0):

You should think about using a repository pattern to access your list of items.  Your viewmodels should work against an abstraction of this repository (e.g. IPeopleRepository), and you should pass a concrete implementation of this repository into your viewmodel via injection (e.g. through constructor injection).  Your concrete implementation can call your communication model to retrieve the list of items.

Typically, your repository will return a collection type which is not specific to WPF.  You'll probably want to wrap this in an ObservableCollection on your viewmodel, so that the UI is notified of changes to the collection.

Whether each viewmodel retrieves a new reference to this collection, or if they all access the same collection, will depend on your use case, but as long as the collection is exposed as a property on your DataContext (typically your viewmodel), then you'll be able to bind to the collection to display and update it from the view.